# What does Crockford mean: "Javascript depends on global variables for linkage"?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

In *Javascript: The Good Parts* Crockford writes that "Javascript depends on the global variable for linkage." I understand that in javascript if you declare a variable outside a function it "is in the [global namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)" -- meaning you can access it anywhere in the program. I sort of understand how [linkage](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=41) limits where in a C++ program you can access a variable (regardless of its scope). With that said, what does Crockford mean?

Comment: Can you add the quote with it's surrounding context and cite it the way you should actually cite a book?

Answer (score 1):

I think what he means is that global variables are how you communicate with libraries. For example jquery uses the global variable $, underscore uses _, etc. You link to the libs through a global name.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing

> All the top-level variables of all compilation units are tossed
>   together in a global namespace called the global object. This is a bad
>   thing because global variables are evil, and in JavaScript they are
>   fundamental. Fortunately, as we will see, JavaScript also gives us the
>   tools to mitigate this problem.

What Crockford is referring to, I think, is the absence of module or namespace-like mechanisms in JS to segregate and modularize chunks of functionality at a macro level, where those chunks are explicit about what they are exposing (export), or what they are using from other chunks (import). However, as he points out, JS does provide the ability, albeit imperfectly, to do this through existing language features, and the world has not come to an end. At the same time, this problem is now being addressed on a number of fronts, notably the ES6 module mechanism.